# Make a phone call with qt 4.6.3

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, telephony, phone-call

I need to trigger a phone call from a Qt application. I looked to previous post without find a complete answer.
I need to make it with qt 4.6.3. I'm quite new to symbian development, I'm using the last nokiaSDK.
It MUST work ONLY on n97 and E71.

Can Anybody provide a solution?

May be a solution exec an extenal process using QProcess?

Comment: why 4.6.3 and not Nokia SDK 1.0? The SDK contains all kinds of mobile-related APIs.

Comment: I'm using the nokia SDK, which is the API you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like currently none of Qt APIs (including QtMobility) allows to do it. However, you can use native Symbian C++ API - CTelephony class. There are some examples showing how to make a phone call using this class. The obvious disadvantage is that it won't work on any other platform than Symbian.

You may be interested in this example: http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/Qt_for_Symbian_Developers_Library/GUID-B4DA6005-3037-4FF8-82D5-BA748532E648.html#GUID-B4DA6005-3037-4FF8-82D5-BA748532E648. It shows how to mix Symbian C++ code with Qt code, and it also uses CTelephony, so you just need to change method call from GetPhoneId() to DialNewCall(). Don't forget to add appropriate library (etel3rdparty.lib) in your .pro file.